# Does WinRT still have the same old UI threading restrictions?

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime

In WinForms, pretty much all your UI is thread-specific. You have to use `[STAThread]` so that the common dialogs will work, and you can't (safely) access a UI element from any thread other than the one that created it. From what I've heard, that's because that's just how Windows works -- window handles are thread-specific.

In WPF, these same restrictions were kept, because ultimately it's still building on top of the same Windows API, still window handles (though mostly just for top-level windows), etc. In fact, WPF even made things *more* restrictive, because you can't even access things like bitmaps across threads.

Now along comes WinRT, a whole new way of accessing Windows -- a fresh, clean slate. Are we still stuck with the same old threading restrictions (specifically: only being able to manipulate a UI control from the thread that created it), or have they opened this up?

Comment: I hope we have the same threading model. It would be insane to allow a free for all or enforce internal locks everywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would *expect* it to be the same model - but *much* easier to use, at least from C# and VB, with the new async handling which lets you write a synchronous-looking method which just uses "await" when it needs to wait for a long-running task to complete before proceeding.

Given the emphasis on making asynchronous code easier to write, it would be surprising for MS to forsake the efficiency of requiring single-threaded access to the UI at the same time.

Comment: As I understand it, "await" doesn't say anything about *which thread* to run the continuation on; it might run on a worker thread. So that wouldn't make async UI-related code any easier; you'd still be manually writing lots of code to marshal calls to the UI thread.

Comment: @Joe: While await itself doesn't require anything (the specification just says what the generated code will call), it depends on what the awaitable does. By default, `Task<T>` will capture the current context and schedule the continuation on the same context - so if you perform an `await` within a UI thread, the continuation will also execute on the UI thread. That's one of the big selling points of async/await - that you *don't* need to write lots of code to do the marshalling.

Answer (score 5):

The threading model is identical.  There is still a notion of single threaded and multi-threaded apartments (STA/MTA), it must be initialized by a call to [RoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Which behaves very much like CoInitialize in name, argument and error returns.  The user interface thread is single threaded, confirmed at 36:00 in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-875T).

Comment: I don't recall anything from that talk that refers to the UI thread, and there's nothing about it at 36:00. At 36:54 he says "Most of your application code is going to run in a single-threaded apartment" -- is that what you're referring to? But that sounds like he's just talking about common practice; after all, STA is easier to code for. That doesn't seem to definitively say that UI in WinRT *requires* a single-threaded apartment.

Comment: He demonstrates the main thread being initialized to STA.  Add that you're not allowed to create your own thread in WinRT, only invoke async and there are not a heckofalot of options left.

Comment: Hmm... I do remember seeing that you can only do threading with Task, and that's not really meant for showing UI, so I suppose you're right about being stuck with the initial threading model. He's doing an HTML5 app, though, and that thread init was all happening inside the host EXE for HTML5 apps. Have you run across anything that says whether XAML apps are also restricted to STA?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML/CSS UI model is inherently single threaded (until the advent of web workers recently, JS didn't support threads).  Xaml is also single threaded (because it's *really* hard for developers to write code to a multithreaded GUI).

Answer (score 2):

The underlying threading model does have some key differences. When your application starts, an ASTA (Application STA) is created to run your UI code as I showed in the talk. This ASTA does not allow reentrancy - you will not receive unrelated calls while making an outgoing call. This is a significant difference from STAs.

You are allowed to create async workitems  - see the [Windows.System.Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR229642) namespace. These workitem threads are automatically initialized to MTA. As Larry mentioned, webworkers are the JS equivalent concept.

Your UI components are thread affined. See the [Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.aspx) for information on how to execute code on the UI thread. You can check out the threading sample for some example code to update the UI from an async operation.

Comment: And a link for the [threading sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Pool-Sample-5aa60454#content). Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links :)

Answer (score 1):

Things are different in pretty important ways.

While it's true the underlying threading model is the same, your question is generally related to how logical concurrency works with UI, and with respect to this what developers see in Windows 8 will be new.

As you mention most dialogs previously blocked.  For Metro apps many UI components do not block all.  Remember the talk of WinRT being asynchronous?  It applies to UI components also.

For example this .NET 4 code will not necessarily kill your harddrive because the UI call blocks on Show (C# example):

```
bool formatHardDrive = true;
if (MessageBox.Show("Format your harddrive?") == NO)
    formatHardDrive = false;
if (formatHardDrive == true)
    Format();
```

With Windows 8 Metro many UI components like **Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog**, are by default Asynchronous so the Show call would immediately (logically) fall through to the next line of code before the user input is retrieved.

Of course there is an elegant solution to this based on the await/promise design patterns (Javascript example):

```
var md = Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello World!");
md.showAsync().then(function (command) { 
    console.log("pressed: " + command.label); });
```

The point is that while the threading model doesn't change, when most people mention UI and threading they are thinking about logical concurrency and how it affects the programming model.

Overall I think the asynchronous paradigm shift is a positive thing.  It requires a bit of a shift in perspective, but it's consistent with the way other platforms are evolving on both the client and server sides.